# ocaml module and program in same file

Tags: module, ocaml

Is it possible in ocaml to have a `.ml` file which provides a function to be used from another file but can also be used as a standalone program?

Let me clarify with an example. In Python, you can do this:

```
#This file is square.py

def my_square(i) :
    print "square of %d is %d" % (i,i*i)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    my_square(10)
```

Now, I can run the above as a standalone program : `python square.py`  but I can also include it from another file by saying `import square`  to get access to the `square` function.

How (if possible) does one do this in ocaml?
Thanks!

Comment: No because this trick in python is done by the interpreter, its determined at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal translation to OCaml would be:

```
 let my_square x = x * x

 let () = 
   if Sys.argv.(0) = "square" then
      print_int (my_square 10)
```

There is no magical `__main__` name in OCaml, but you can mimic it. This module will provide a `my_square` function if it is just linked. But if the program has name `"square"` it will print the result of `my_square(10)`.

Answer (score 1):

Modules can include effectful expressions in OCaml, but there's no clean way to conditionalize them as in the Python example. Probably the most reasonable way to achieve the same effect is to move the conditional code into another module and use that as your program.

This could be as simple as wrapping the program part in a `run` function and calling that in the other module. This has the advantage that any use of module internals would not require an interface change (other than exposing `run`).